# Is dynamic importing with React lazy or NextJS dynamic vulnerable to injection

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, xss, next.js, code-injection

React `lazy`

```
const Component = lazy(() => import(`../${element}`));
```

NextJS `dynamic`

```
const Component = dynamic(() => import(`../${element}`));
```

These examples have a relative path. However, in my app I also lazy load with element as the only argument to the import function e.g.

```
const Component = lazy(() => import(element));
```

Can element be tampered with for injection of XSS? and if so how can I protect against it. Is there a way to encode the variable to ensure it is safe?